# MQTT Dart rest API

Tags: dart, flutter, mqtt

I already have a rest API dart server, `aqueduct`, and i wish to have a separate MQTT server which will accept requests from the client.

I have read some MQTT specs, and read through he mqtt_client of dart

have not code: here is my current aqueduct api endoints:
`/api/docs
/api/books
/api/books/author`

I need assistance, on understanding what should i do to setup a mqtt dart server to accept requests, and what should my client looks like too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort answer, you don't.

Slightly longer answer,

First there is no concept of a MQTT server, there is a MQTT broker.

A HTTP server represents a request/response architecture, a MQTT broker represents a Pub/Sub architecture.

The MQTT broker sits between many MQTT clients and allows client to publish a message on a topic to N other clients that are subscribed to that topic (where N can 0 to many).

So to solve your problem, you could run a MQTT broker and then write a client that subscribes to a number of topic (e.g. api/books<sup>1</sup>) and processes messages it receive. It could respond by publishing a message to a separate topic (but there is no concept of direct response to the original publisher<sup>2</sup>) that the original publisher could be subscribed to.

<sup>1</sup> MQTT topics should not start with a leading `/`, while allowed in the spec it breaks things like shared subscriptions.

<sup>2</sup> MQTT v5 allows you to add meta data that indicates that a message is a response (but still not direct request response)

Comment: still trying to understand here:( what login my broker will have? what my client will look like? there is a flutter library [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mqtt_client] will this lib help me with client / broker and client. i am having trouble here, would it be too much to ask for an example.

Comment: A broker wouldn't log in to anywhere, clients can authenticate against a broker when they connect. The name of the library pretty clearly shows it's a MQTT client. Asking for Examples is off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Can i create 1 login details on my broker, and have all my clients use same 1 at same time?